# React - httpOnly cookies not getting set from the express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

Vite + React: `http://localhost:5173`

Express: `http://localhost:3000`

Here is the code in the express server's login route:

```
const mycookie = cookie.serialize("jwt", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true, // Set the HTTP-only flag
    secure: true, // Set the secure flag
    sameSite: "none", 
    path: "/", // Set the path of the cookie to '/'
    maxAge: 3600, // Set the maximum age of the cookie to 1 hour
  });

  // Set the cookie in the response headers
  res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", mycookie);

  res.json({
    accessToken,
    refreshToken,
  });
```

Here is my cors config:

```
const allowedOrigins = require("./allowedOrigins");

const corsOptions = {
  crendials: true,
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin));
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
};
```

Here is my handleSubmit function in the frontend (gets called when the user clicks submit):

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log("Login");
    // axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login", { email, password });
  };
```

Whenever the request is made to the server. The response header does contain the set-Header to set the jwt token but I am not able to see it in my applications tab under cookies in devtools. A pre-flight request also comes in which probably clears the cookie.

My networks tab:

[image]

The xhr request:

[image]

The OPTIONS request:

[image]

The Applications tab:

[image]

However, when I disable CORS in the browser, the cookie is getting set.

Networks tab (NOTICE: No PreFlight request)

[image]

Applications tab:

[image]

I tried working out different answers from stackoverflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71688058), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64760619), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68970499), and many more along with a [reddit post on a similar issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/vxvdib/cookie_not_being_set_in_react_app_express_backend/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) but nothing has worked.

P.S. : I already tried using `credentials: true`

Comment: Your immediate issue has got nothing to do with CORS. An insecure Web origin (e.g. one that uses `http` as its scheme) cannot set a `Secure` cookie.

Comment: I tried commenting the line secure: true, it doesn't work..... And if a secure cookie cannot be stored in http scheme, why does it get stored in a CORS disabled browser.

Comment: Commenting out `Secure: true` isn't enough because `SameSite: None` requires `Secure` (at least in Chromium browsers). I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "CORS-disabled browser", but I'm guessing that running the browser with the `--disable-web-security` flag disables more security checks than those covered by the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @noobCoder19 did you found a solution for this? I have the same issue in my nextjs, express nodejs app. set-cookie is displaying in the response header.